# How to solve the unexpected '}' in "}" in a user-made function contaning an ifelse statement?

Tags: r

So I have this function:

```
library(worms)
library(dplyr)
worms_from_species_list<-function(file_name,file_location,header=T){
  if(header==T){
    setwd(file_location)
    lista<-read_tsv(file_name)
    names(lista)<-"Species"
    worms_df<-wormsbynames(lista[,"Species"])
  }else{
    setwd(file_location)
    lista<-read_tsv(file_name)
    worms_df<-wormsbynames(lista)
  }
  worms_df<-worms_df%>%
    mutate(new_name = ifelse(status=="unaccepted" & !is.na(status),valid_name,
                             ifelse(status=="accepted" & !is.na(status),name,name))
  return(worms_df)
}
```

However, I can't even run it to begin with because it returns the following errors:

```
Error: unexpected ')' in:
"  worms_df<-worms_df%>%
                             ifelse(status=="accepted" & !is.na(status),name,name))"
> }
Error: unexpected '}' in "}"
```

Does anyone have any idea what it might be?

Comment: Add a close-paren after `name))`, into `name)))`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Most IDEs provide paren-matching in some form. In this case, it suggests that you need to close out the `mutate` call.

In RStudio, for instance, when the cursor is to the right of `name))`, it indicates that the last right-paren on that line matches the left-paren of `ifelse`:

[image]

The `|` is the cursor, and the background-gray `(` is the matching left-paren.

Similarly (though it's less commonly used), emacs/ess can show it if configured as such:

[image]

Here, both the right-paren and its matching left-paren are highlighted with a blue background.

Another trick in RStudio (and other IDEs) is to indent rows and see where they pan out. You'll see that I did that in before the first screenshot above, and you can see that it thinks `return(worms_df)` is *within* the `mutate`.

The solution looks like this:

```r
worms_from_species_list<-function(file_name,file_location,header=T){
  if(header==T){
    setwd(file_location)
    lista<-read_tsv(file_name)
    names(lista)<-"Species"
    worms_df<-wormsbynames(lista[,"Species"])
  }else{
    setwd(file_location)
    lista<-read_tsv(file_name)
    worms_df<-wormsbynames(lista)
  }
  worms_df<-worms_df%>%
    mutate(new_name = ifelse(status=="unaccepted" & !is.na(status),valid_name,
                             ifelse(status=="accepted" & !is.na(status),name,name)))
  return(worms_df)
}
```